# whenever gem failing on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, capistrano, whenever

after doing **cap qa deploy** in the terminal, I get the following error at the end of the deploy:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd [removed]/releases/[removed] && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab [removed] --set environment=production --roles db'" on [removed]
```

The first thing I'm confused about is when I use capistrano and deploy, why is it running the whenever command on the db role? Shouldn't it automatically run the command on the app role?

**On server:**
Bundler version 1.3.5

**gemfile:**

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

**schedule.rb:**

```
env 'PATH', ENV['PATH']

set :output, "/log/cron.log"
set :stage, :environment_variable

every 5.minutes, :roles => [:app] do
  runner "[removed]"
end

every 1.day, :at => '0:01 am' do
    command "[removed]"
end
```

**deploy.rb:**

```
require 'capistrano/log_with_awesome'
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "[REMOVED]"

set :scm, :git 

set :repository,  "[REMOVED]"

set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache 

set :user, "[REMOVED]"
set :password, "[REMOVED]"
set :deploy_to, "[REMOVED]"

set :keep_releases, 5

task :qa do

    set :domain, "[REMOVED]"
    role :web, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # Your HTTP server, Nginx
    role :app, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # This may be the same as your `Web` server
    set :env, "test"
end


task :production do

    set :domain, "[REMOVED]"
    role :web, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # Your HTTP server, Nginx
    role :app, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # This may be the same as your `Web` server
    set :env, "production"
end


set :use_sudo, false
default_run_options[:pty] = true


role :db, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED], primary: true, :no_release => true}

after "deploy:setup", "deploy:chown"

namespace :bundle do 

    task :install, {:roles => :app} do
        run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --deployment --without development test"
    end

end

before "deploy:assets:precompile" do

    transfer :up, "config/application.yml", "#{shared_path}/application.yml", :via => :scp

    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/application.yml #{release_path}/config/application.yml"

end

namespace :whenever do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do 

    task :execute_migrations, :roles => :app do
        puts "RUNNING DB MIGRATIONS"
        run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{env} db:migrate"
    end

    task :chown do
        run "#{try_sudo} chown -R #{user} #{deploy_to}"
    end

    task :restart_nginx, {:roles => :web} do
        run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    end

    before "deploy:restart_nginx", "deploy:execute_migrations"

    after :deploy, "deploy:restart_nginx"

    after "deploy:restart_nginx", "deploy:cleanup"

    after "deploy:update", "whenever:start"


end
```

**When I ssh into the server and run the command there:**

```
[REMOVED]@[REMOVED]/current$ bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir [REMOVED] in PATH, mode 040777
[write] crontab file updated
```

**I checked the crontab file by running: crontab -l and this is what I got in the crontab:**

```
[REMOVED]@[REMOVED]/current$ crontab -l
PATH=/[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/shims:/home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

#Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED]/config/schedule.rb
PATH=/[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/shims:/home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED] && script/rails runner -e production '\''/[REMOVED]/current/script/[REMOVED].rb'\'''

1 0 * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/[REMOVED]/current/script/[REMOVED].rb'

#End Whenever generated tasks for: /[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED]/config/schedule.rb
```

**I then get this error because of the first cron job (emailed to my work email):**

```
/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 67: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
/home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140203065556/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/[REMOVED]/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the roles when using your method, set the following:

```
set :whenever_roles,        ->{ :app }
```

It defaults to :db

Other options that can be set:

```
set :whenever_roles,        ->{ :db }
set :whenever_options,      ->{ {:roles => fetch(:whenever_roles)} }
set :whenever_command,      ->{  }
set :whenever_identifier,   ->{ fetch :application }
set :whenever_environment,  ->{ fetch :rails_env, "production" }
set :whenever_variables,    ->{ "environment=#{fetch :whenever_environment}" }
set :whenever_update_flags, ->{ "--update-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier} --set #{fetch :whenever_variables}" }
set :whenever_clear_flags,  ->{ "--clear-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier}" }
```

https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano/v3/tasks/whenever.rake

### OR

I tend to create custom tasks like the following:

```
namespace :whenever do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab"
  end
end
```

Then have capistrano execute it when I want like so:

```
after "deploy:update", "whenever:start"
```

This way you can reuse/rerun/test this anytime with the following:

```
cap whenever:start
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll reward the bounty to you in 21 hours. It makes me wait.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is failing? 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /[REMOVED]/releases/[REMOVED] && script/rails runner -e production '\''/[REMOVED]/current/script/[REMOVED].rb'\'''

Comment: thanks for responding man. The error's at the bottom of the question details

Comment: I'll make a new question And shoot over a link

Comment: Looks like it might be an RVM issue with multiple ruby versions are installed.... Do you have multiple rubies installed?

Comment: Yeah I have multiple rubies installed

Comment: @PavanKatepalli I've updated my answer with a better one that uses the whenever/capistrano integration like you originally were... As far as the other issue... I'll keep looking..

Comment: Oh wait I have only one ruby installed, and it's 1.9.3. Also, I'm using rbenv on the ubuntu server, but using rvm on my local environment. Maybe that's why this line in my schedule.rb file is messing things up: env 'PATH', ENV['PATH']. I guess removing it and deploying might fix things?

Comment: After doing what I suggested above I get this as an error emailed to me: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 67: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: [REMOVED]/releases/20140203065556: No such file or directory

Comment: @PavanKatepalli is 20140203065556 the latest release? I assume you are using the `whenever:start`? Try setting `set :whenever_roles, ->{ :app }` and let me know...

Comment: Did it `cd` to the COMPLETE path?

Comment: I just checked the releases folder and 20140203065556 isn't even in there. Sorry you were right.

Comment: @PavanKatepalli there are several reasons as to why that happened... If you can post up your updated deploy.rb, might help

Comment: I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566132/rails-script-using-whenever-gem-error-rvm-add-to-path-command-not-found

Comment: any ideas? I'm out on my luck.