# rails script using whenever gem error: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cron, capistrano, whenever

I'm using capistrano and the whenever gem.

Capistrano deploys and updates the crontab on our ubuntu server with the cronjob detailed out in our schedule.rb file.

But the cronjob doesn't happen. It fails and emails me every 5 minutes this error:

```
/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 67: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
/home/pkatepalli/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /home/pkatepalli/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/pkatepalli/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pkatepalli/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

The weird part is we're deploying with a different username than pkatepalli. pkatepalli is my username on the server. That explains why it's emailing me the error - I think.

Also, we're using ruby 1.9.3 not 1.9.1. I'm not sure why it's not using the right ruby version.

**On server:**

```
Bundler version 1.3.5

ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]

$ rbenv version

1.9.3-p448 (set by /[REMOVED]/current/.ruby-version)
```

**But interestingly enough in the current directory there's ruby 1.9.1, which I'm confused by:**

```
/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
```

**gemfile:**

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
```

**schedule.rb:**
*I've tried uncommenting: env 'PATH', ENV['PATH'], but the PATH that gets put into the schedule.rb file doesn't help. 
Locally we're using RVM instead of rbenv (which is being used on the server). I'm not sure if that screws up the path if we set: env 'PATH', ENV['PATH']*

```
#env 'PATH', ENV['PATH']

#set :output, "/log/cron.log"
#set :stage, :environment_variable

every 5.minutes, :roles => [:app] do
  runner "Model.method"
end
```

**deploy.rb:**

```
require 'capistrano/log_with_awesome'
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :application, "[REMOVED]"

set :scm, :git 

set :repository,  "[REMOVED]"

set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache 

set :user, "[REMOVED]"
set :password, "[REMOVED]"
set :deploy_to, "[REMOVED]"

set :keep_releases, 5

task :qa do

    set :domain, "[REMOVED]"
    role :web, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # Your HTTP server, Nginx
    role :app, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # This may be the same as your `Web` server
    set :env, "test"
end


task :production do

    set :domain, "[REMOVED]"
    role :web, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # Your HTTP server, Nginx
    role :app, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED]} # This may be the same as your `Web` server
    set :env, "production"
end


set :use_sudo, false
default_run_options[:pty] = true


role :db, "[REMOVED]", {:port => [REMOVED], primary: true, :no_release => true}

after "deploy:setup", "deploy:chown"

namespace :bundle do 

    task :install, {:roles => :app} do
        run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --deployment --without development test"
    end

end

before "deploy:assets:precompile" do

    transfer :up, "config/application.yml", "#{shared_path}/application.yml", :via => :scp

    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/application.yml #{release_path}/config/application.yml"

end

namespace :whenever do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do 

    task :execute_migrations, :roles => :app do
        puts "RUNNING DB MIGRATIONS"
        run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{env} db:migrate"
    end

    task :chown do
        run "#{try_sudo} chown -R #{user} #{deploy_to}"
    end

    task :restart_nginx, {:roles => :web} do
        run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
    end

    before "deploy:restart_nginx", "deploy:execute_migrations"

    after :deploy, "deploy:restart_nginx"

    after "deploy:restart_nginx", "deploy:cleanup"

    after "deploy:update", "whenever:start"


end
```

**When I ssh into the server and run crontab -l in the app's current directory:**

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/config/schedule.rb
#0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143 && script/rails runner -e production '\''Model.method'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: [REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/config/schedule.rb
```

When I run the cron job on the server like this I get this result:

```
:/[REMOVED]/current$ rails runner -e production '\''Model.method'\'''
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
/[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined (SyntaxError)
\Model.method'
 ^
(eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

When I do it like this. I get this:

```
[REMOVED]/current$ rails runner Model.method
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that [REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/log/development.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
[REMOVED]/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" ([REMOVED]) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__249672195884464632__prepare__2220886522034318467__callbacks'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

**In response to Leonid Shevtsov's answer:**

I ran:

```
rails runner -e production 'Model.method'
```

and I got this:

```
[REMOVED]/current$ rails runner -e production 'Model.methodName'
/[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': undefined method `methodName' for #<Class:0x0000000570d668> (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
    from /[REMOVED]/releases/20140204194143/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

when I run crontab -l, I get the whenever generated crons

Comment: Try running the cron job script by hand and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I updated my question with the results of running the cron job script by hand

Comment: Could you give us the contents of `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`?

Answer (score 1):

a) 1.9.1 is the "base" version of Ruby 1.9.3 (1.9.3 is considered to be a version of Ruby 1.9.1); it's normal that you see it in the paths.

b) the command line in cron is escaping quotes; the proper way to check it manually is `rails runner -e production 'Model.method'`

c) are you sure the error isn't arriving from a locally installed cron job? (check with `crontab -l`)

Comment: hey Leonid I updated my question with details reflecting what you asked in your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @PavanKatepalli i meant run `crontab -l` on your development machine and see if you accidentally installed the cronjobs there.

Comment: I ran it on my local machine in my rails app, and it returns: crontab: no crontab for pkatepalli

Comment: I'm on a mac so there's no crontab

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is kind of complicated and some debugging info is missing so I will try to take a guess.

- First of all it seems that you have both `rvm` and `rbenv` installed on your system which is [not a very good idea](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation). Try uninstalling one of the two, or better yet uninstall both and reinstall the one you prefer.
- In your deploy script it seems you have rolled your own whenever capistrano tasks. This is not bad, but `whenever` already [provides this out of the box](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration) with better support (e.g. rollbacks). You can also get better feedback on your future problems.

Those are potential pitfalls but their are not probably the cause of your problems. You seem to have messed things up regarding the linux users and their permissions. As far as I understand there are two users on your production system: `pkatepalli` and another one which you commented out, lets call him `deployer`.

From what I see you are trying to set everything up to work from the perspective of `deployer` which is a good practice.

- I assume the capistrano `user` variable is set to `deployer`. If not this is the root of your problem. This is the user which capistrano uses to log in and issue your commands.
- Also it seems that when you run `crontab -l` you see the cron jobs correctly *but* if you are logged in with `pkatepalli` when you run the command then this is your problem. You have written your tasks to the wrong user's crontab. If this has happened it more likely means either that you run the `whenever` command from the wrong user during cap deploy (in which case you need to check which is the logged in user during cap) or you have actually run the `whenever` command from both users and you are only getting errors for `pkatepalli` (clear your crontab before experimenting again). If it still looks it is ok then you can try passing the [`-u username`](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/bin/whenever#L29) option to `whenever` command (you probably need `sudo` for this).
- To set up the `deployer` user properly you can follow the instructions by [`capistrano`](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)